# steps for bluetooth printer for Android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am interested to develop bluetooth printer app for Android so please guide me how to begin
it? 
Is there any free third party library for that ?

Comment: I still am able to find solution for it , has anybody have done any application related to bluetooth printer (or only printer ) for android , please do free to commnent it.

Answer (score 3):

Star Micronics has an SDK for Android printing via Bluetooth (as well as ethernet, wifi, and USB). You can download it here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx.

You can't print natively from Android at this point in time so the alternate solutions are a 3rd party API, finding a 3rd party printing app, or writing your own printer support.

In my experience, it's best to use an API and not an external app. The biggest reason is you get total control over printer behavior. Using an external app is limiting because you can't customize your print outs the way you want to. Writing a printer driver is too hard because you need to intimately know the device for perfect support... the API gives you full control over the device without all the frustration of re-engineering the whole process.

The Star SDK I linked you to has an API and a really nice sample app that lets you test and customized printer functions to see them in action. It's well documented too.

If you choose this way, you can send plain text to the printer along with commands. The API handles converting the data into what the printer can understand.